# JQuery add padding to original padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is probably quite simple but I can't figure it out.
I want to use jquery to add padding-top to a div in addition to it's original padding-top. My code so far is:

```
var headH = $('#header').outerHeight();
var mastPad = $('#masthead').css('padding-top');
$('#masthead').css('padding-top', mastPad + headH);
```

This results in huge amounts of padding I presume because JQuery keeps multiplying the padding. I need to find a way to grab the original padding-top and then add to it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling this multiple times? If so there is no "original padding" you would need to store it.

Comment: Yikes, sorry, not sure what you mean @epascarello
I think I am just calling it once.

Comment: How does it keep growing? Plus you do not remove the px/%/em from the value.

Comment: I assume this is wrapped in an onload wrapper?  or is it in another function?  please post more code that shows invovation

Comment: try `alert` or `console.log` `headH`, `mastPad` and `mastPad + headH` to see what you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('#masthead').css('padding-top')` returns a *string*, not a number, so it could be that `headH` is being *appended* to that string, not added to its numeric value;

Perhaps:

```
$('#masthead').css('padding-top', parseInt(mastPad, 10) + headH);
```

`parseInt` will parse what it can find, and then ignore the rest. So `"42px"` becomes `42` (whereas using a unary `+` or `Number` will choke on the px part).

Here's a self-contained example, replicates the problem for me on Chrome with the `with` div and not the `without` div:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var top;

  var $without = $("#without");

  top = $without.css("padding-top");
  snippet.log("top = [" + top + "] (type: " + typeof top + ")");
  $without.css("padding-top", top + 100);

  var $with = $("#with");
  top = parseInt($with.css("padding-top"), 10);
  snippet.log("top = [" + top + "] (type: " + typeof top + ")");
  $with.css("padding-top", top + 100);
  
  snippet.log("Updated");
}, 2000);
```

```css
div {
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="without">We'll update this div without <code>parseInt</code></div>
<div id="with">We'll update this div with <code>parseInt</code></div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I'm a bit surprised that "20px100" ends up being a really big pad, but...

Answer (score 0):

outerHeight includes top, bottom padding and borders.

Comment: It would be helpful to include why this answer is applicable to the user's situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can store that variable in the global context and then protect it from incrementing, like so:

```
var originalPad;
var ranOnce = false;
function GrowPadding() {
   var headH = $('#header').outerHeight();
   if(!ranOnce) {
      mastPad = parseInt($('#masthead').css('padding-top'), 10);
      ranOnce = true;
   }
   $('#masthead').css('padding-top', mastPad + headH);
}
```